# How to highlight (select) an entire row given a cell that comes from a hyperlink

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I have Sheet1 and Sheet2. In Sheet1 I have a table with a column of hyperlinks that redirect to defined cells in Sheet2. What I'd like to do is to have automatically selected the entire row of the cell in Sheet2 that I've been redirected to.

I have tried this in Sheet2 code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Target.EntireRow.Select
End Sub
```

Which selects the entire row for a given selected cell. However this is not very comfortable as it's a permanent selection and, let's say, when I want to select a column it selects the whole sheet. What is a better way of doing this?

I think it is important to mention that I don't want to change the format of the rows in order to highlight them, I only want to select them.

Comment: check that Target is only one cell

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `Target.EntireRow.Select` triggers another `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event. You need to prevent that with `Application.EnableEvents = False`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.EntireRow.Select
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

But maybe you could use the `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink` which could be a better choice.

---

Best approach would be to change the hyperlink to point to the whole row instead of a single cell. So instead of pointing to A5 point the hyperlink to 5:5 no VBA needed then.

Comment: I don't know why but when I use Application.EnableEvents=False, the problem is still there. If I click on, for example, column P, as if I were to select the whole column, then it selects the whole sheet.

Comment: @ALawliet that's because `EntireRow` of a full column is the entire sheet. Try `If Target.Rows.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub` as first statement.

Comment: But why don't you just change your hyperlinks to full rows? Eg if your hyperlink points to A5 and you want it to select the full row change the hyperlink to point to 5:5 instead. This way you don't need any VBA at all.

Comment: Hey! I didn't think of that, althought I don't know exactly how I'd do that, since I am creating the hyperlink cells with:

=ISNA(HYPERLINK("#"&"pfe!"&ADDRESS(MATCH(A18;pfe!A:A;0);2);VLOOKUP(A18;pfe!A:A;1;FALSE));"")

I'll try and concatenate row instead of address

Comment: `MATCH` returns the row number so you don't need the `ADDRESS`. I think a `=ISNA(HYPERLINK("#"&"pfe!"&MATCH(A18;pfe!A:A;0)&":"&MATCH(A18;pfe!A:A;0);VLOOKUP(A18;pfe!A:A;1;FALSE));"")` should work.

Comment: @ALawliet did you test the formula above?

Answer (score 0):

## FollowHyperlink

### Highlights

- In the `FollowHyperlink` event, `Target` is a `Hyperlink` object.
- If the `Address` property **and** the `SubAddress` property of a `Hyperlink` object are different than `""`, it will point to a location in **another** workbook.
- If the `Address` property of a `Hyperlink` object is `""`, then it will point to a location in this workbook.
- If additionally the `SubAddress` property does **not** contain an exclamation mark `!`, it **could** point to a **defined name**.
- If the `SubAddress` property **does** contain an exclamation mark `!`, it will contain **single quotes** `'` when the sheet name contains **spaces**.

### The Code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)

    Const cSheet As Variant = "Sheet2"   ' Target Worksheet Name/Index

    Dim i As Integer        ' Names Counter
    Dim strRng As String    ' Target Range Address Builder
    Dim strSheet As String  ' Target Worksheet Name Builder

    ' Check if hyperlink points to a location outside this workbook.
    If Target.Address <> "" Then Exit Sub

    ' Assign the value of Target.SubAddress to Target Range Address Builder.
    strRng = Target.SubAddress

    With ThisWorkbook ' Me.Parent

        ' Check if hyperlink points to a named range ("!").
        If InStr(strRng, "!") = 0 Then
            ' Loop through all names.
            For i = 1 To .Names.Count
                ' Compare their NAME to Target Range Address Builder.
                If .Names(i).Name = strRng Then
                    strRng = Right(.Names(i).RefersTo, Len(.Names(i).RefersTo) _
                            - 1) ' Remove "=".
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            If i > .Names.Count Then Exit Sub ' Name not found.
        End If

        ' Calculate worksheet name.
        strSheet = Replace(Left(strRng, InStr(strRng, "!") - 1), "'", "")
        ' Check if calculated worksheet name is equal to Target Worksheet Name.
        If strSheet <> .Worksheets(cSheet).Name Then Exit Sub
        ' Calculate the Target Range Address.
        strRng = Right(strRng, Len(strRng) - InStr(strRng, "!"))

        ' Select the entire row of Target Range.
        .Worksheets(strSheet).Range(strRng).EntireRow.Select

    End With

End Sub
```

### Why doesn't the following code always work?

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: For some reason this does not work, maybe I should save the file in a specific format? (Yes I have put it in the worksheet where the hyperlink is)

Comment: @A.Lawliet. I have added the new solution to my answer.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I guess it doesn't always work because right in the moment you click the link, `ActiveCell` changes to the target of the link. But also right in that moment `FollowHyperlink` is triggered. Even if VBA does not support multi threading the link click is run by the Excel application (which supports multi threading) and not by VBA. So sometimes the VBA event comes first sometimes the `ActiveCell` change comes first in multi threading. • That's why in VBA everything with a `*Active*` has to be handled with care, the active thing can change any moment and it is not very reliable.